# What parameters would I put in this function 'copy' to copy a to b?

Tags: c, pointers, parameters, structure

```
struct info
{
    int val;
};

void copy(struct info ** dst, struct info * src)
{
    *dst = (struct info *)malloc(sizeof(struct info));
    **dst = *src;
}

int main()
{
    struct info *a, *b; 

    a = (struct info *)malloc(sizeof(struct info));
    a -> val = 7;
    copy( , );

    a -> val = 9;
    printf("%d", b->val);
}
```

I have tried `(b, a)`, `(*b, *a)`, `(b, *a)` and so one but the argument is always unexpected by the compiler. Have been trying for an hour with no result - just a half melted brain.

Comment: Trying to put `*` everywhere won't solve your problems.

Comment: You need to use `&` instead `*` while passing to `copy`.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument is supposed to be a pointer to a pointer. Since `b` is a pointer, you need to take its address, which is `&b`.

The second argument is supposed to be a pointer. `a` is a pointer, so you just pass it directly.

```
copy(&b, a);
```

`*` is for indirecting through a pointer to access what it points to. That's the exact opposite of what you want, which is to get a pointer to the variable itself. You use `*` inside the `copy` function to access what the pointers given point to.

BTW, you should also see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

And don't forget to free the structures when you're done using them.